# Use PHP Code in Custom variable Magento

Tags: php, email, magento, subscription, newsletter

I'm trying to create a new Variable (System -> Custom variable) to use in Email tempalte  (System -> Transactional Emails)
As you know when we create new custom variable we just only have 2 options :

```
1) Variable HTML Value
2) Variable Plain Value
```

How can I use php script like that

```
<?php
$a = 1;
$b = 2;
echo $a+b;
?>
```

By the way, I tried to insert ubsubcriber link to email template

```
Mage::getModel('newsletter/subscriber')->loadByEmail($email)->getUnsubscriptionLink();
```

Because "{{var subscriber.getUnsubscriptionLink()}}" doesn't work , it return NULL,
Thanks

Comment: Are you looking to access custom variables with php ?

Comment: Yes, because I'm new with Magento, so can you tell me more detail about that, very thank you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Magento: how do I access custom variables in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6221054/magento-how-do-i-access-custom-variables-in-php)

Comment: Hello @tungcan, Have you get any solution?